# How to make a variable clickable from an AJAX/php query script

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

After advice taken from the community i started work on a AJAX/php script to retrieve data based on a variable from a MySQL database. It works reasonably well now i'd like to be able to click on any of the variables that are shown and that take you to another page whilst remembering your selection. Is this possible?

Here is a [link to my website.](http://nuttyhosting.tech:1234/PokemonFight.php)

Here is my PokemonFight.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getpokemon.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%
        }
        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px
        }
    </style>
    <title>Pokemon Fight!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center>Pokemon Fight!</center></h1>
<h2>Select your type!</h2>

<form>
  <select name="test" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a Pokemon Type!:</option>
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Fire</option>
  <option value="3">Fighting</option>
  <option value="4">Water</option>
  <option value="5">Flying</option>
  <option value="6">Grass</option>
  <option value="7">Poison</option>
  <option value="8">Electric</option>
  <option value="9">Ground</option>
  <option value="10">Psychic</option>
  <option value="11">Rock</option>
  <option value="12">Ice</option>
  <option value="13">Bug</option>
  <option value="14">Dragon</option>
  <option value="15">Ghost</option>
  <option value="16">Dark</option>
  <option value="17">Steel</option>
  <option value="18">Fairy</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Pokemon info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my getpokemon.php code:

```
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','pokemon');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"pokemon");
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Pokemon Name</th>
<th>PokedexID</th>
<th>Move 1</th>
<th>Move 2</th>
<th>Move 3</th>
<th>Move 4</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PokedexID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Pokemon_Move_1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Pokemon_Move_2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Pokemon_Move_3'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Pokemon_Move_4'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The folowing piece of code was what i wasn't understanding but replacing what i previously with this new piece of code added a hyperlink on the Pokemon name which links to another page that i'm creating with an ID value of the PokedexID. Hope this helps anyone that was as stuck as i was.

Before Code:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['PokedexID'] . "</td>";
```

After Code:

```
echo "<td><a href=' viewpokemon.php?PokedexID=" . $row["PokedexID"] . "'>" . $row["Pokemon_Name"] . "</a></td>"
```